# RxJava: application dies when exception is thrown

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I am trying to perform some IO operation in the Schedulers IO thread, and if an exception is thrown, I want to show some Toast to the user (in the mainThread, of course).

For this I use the following code:

```
 try {
        Observable.interval(0, 15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnNext(event -> failingNetworkOperation();)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnError(throwable -> 
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error message", LENGTH_SHORT).show())
            .subscribe();

 } catch(Throwable t)  {
        //THIS CODE IS NEVER REACHED
        //BUT THE APPLICATION DIES.
        t.printStackTrace();
 }
```

When an exception is thrown on method "failingInputOutputOperation", the Throwable IS catched in the "doOnError" consumer, but the application dies.

I sorrounded the whole snippet in a try/catch bloc, but the exception is never caught there.

Why is the application dying and how can I correctly manage the error with RxJava?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire Java stack trace associated with the crash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your app dies because you don't have an error handler in `subscribe`. Put the callback of the `doOnError` there:

```java
    Observable.interval(0, 15, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.io())
        .doOnNext(event -> failingNetworkOperation())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(items -> { }, 
             throwable -> 
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error message", LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        );
```

Comment: Exactly. Thank you very much! So the doOnError doesn't consume the error, it keeps going downstream until the "subscribe", right? Why isn't it catched in the outer try/catch?

Comment: `try-catch` mentality doesn't work in the asynchronous world. The `subscribe` goes async so the thread simply falls out of that `try-catch`.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will give it a thought... Also I am seeing that the "interval" stops emitting after the error, what is happening there? is it canceled or someting?

Comment: Yes. When the `doOnNext` crashes, the sequence is cancelled, including interval.

Comment: And how could I avoid it to be canceled?

Comment: It makes no sense. There is only one error allowed per flow. If you don't want to stop it, don't let it crash into RxJava.